# Typedef struct, pointers and passing pointers to a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Im kinda new to programming, so if someone could help me here id appreciate it!

```
typedef struct /*struct for circle creation*/
{
  int x_coord;
  int y_coord;
  int radius;
} circle, *circlepointer;
```

I need a pointer to a circle, and pass that pointer to a function that returns true if the circle radius is >0, and false otherwise.
How do i pass my *circlepointer to a function and check this? I should be able to do something like circle.radius > 0, in the function

Hope you can help

Comment: Why bother with the `*circlepointer` typedef?  All it does it add another type - and that type obfuscates the fact it's a pointer badly enough you have to put `pointer` in the type name.

Comment: In what way `circlepointer` is better than `circle*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare and define your function in this way

```
int func(circle * c) {
    return c->radius > 0;
}
```

Access a member via pointer can be done with -> operator or by dereferencing the pointer and then just use . operator to access its members

```
(*c).radius 
c->radius
```

then just call it in main

```
circle c = {your_x, your_y, your_radius};
func(&c);
```

Answer (score 3):

The function can be declared like

```
int f( circlepointer c );
```

or

```
int f( const circle *c );
```

and called like

```
circle c = { /*...*/ };

f( &c );
```

Within the function you can access data members of the object like `c->radius` or `( *c ).radius`.

Instead of the return type int you can also use the C type _Bool. Or you can include the header `<stdbool.h>` and write the return type as `bool`.

Pay attention to that these two function declarations

```
int f( const circlepointer c );
```

and

```
int f( const circle *c );
```

are not equivalent. In the first declaration the pointer itself is constant. In the second declaration the object pointed to by the pointer is constant.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, the `radius` member may be accessed in function `f` above through `(*c).radius` or `c->radius`.